# Getting an unusual error using firebase with react native

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, configuration

I am trying to link up firebase to my app so that i can store my habits on a database rather than just have them locally. I have looked up a ton of documentation and downloaded countless firebase packages to try and figure out how to connect my firebase app, but i am still running into a lot of problems.

the error reads:
While trying to resolve module `idb` from file `/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev stuff/personal/90dayz/90DayZ/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js`, the package `/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev stuff/personal/90dayz/90DayZ/node_modules/idb/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/jonnywerthman/Desktop/Dev stuff/personal/90dayz/90DayZ/node_modules/idb/build/index.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

here is what my config file looks like:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID
};

// Initialize Firebase

if (firebase.apps.length === 0){
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
} else {
    app = firebase.app()
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
export default {db, auth}
```

My guess is that either I don't have something downloaded that I should, or I messed up the .env file somehow

Answer (score 0):

You need use https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage for React Native projects

Comment: are you saying that I need to download the package again using npm? or that I imported it wrong?

Comment: you are shared code and these codes are from web project. You need to use react native approach